# find - all .a files except .dll.a files

Tags: regex, find

I'm using "find" on Ubuntu to delete some files.

find -iname "*.a" -delete

deletes all .a files. But I want to keep .dll.a files. Using -regex ".*^(?!dll).a" fails with "Invalid preceding regular expression".

For testing, I use these 4 filenames:
libz.a, libz.dll.a, libintl.a, libintl.dll.a

Comment: Just use `! -name '*.dll'`. You also probably want to add a `-type f`, to avoid deleting more than just files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rm `find . -type f -name "*.a" | grep -v "dll.a"`
```